# Windows 7 Aero snap window resizing: love and hate, partially disable?

Tags: windows-7, resizing

I love the "ease of access" window resizing in Windows 7 that are related to moving the window (move window to left for left half size, to right for right half, up for maximize, shake to get rid of windows) but I HATE when the window resizes while dragging the edges.

Typically the way to disable to functionality is the following:

Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Make the mouse easier to use -> Under 'Make windows easier to manage', check 'Prevent'

Is there any way to keep what I like and prevent what I hate? Back in the days of Windows XP I would tile windows by selecting more than one in the taskbar and tiling. The new taskbar seems to have made that impossible, and I love the new window dragging methods that have replaced it, but I'm starting to get so enraged by not being able to easily customize my window sizes that I may very well sacrifice these useful features to prevent it.

Comment: I found out that I can still use the super+left/right keys to resize the windows. I think my best option, if there is no way to just disable the edge-drag-resizing, is to just turn the feature off completely and use these super+left/right keyboard shortcuts to size my windows.

Comment: any way to do this in Windows 8.1 ? Hate accidentally triggering the maximize snap but can't live without the horizontal snaps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do it natively in Windows, however, there are some apps that might be able to do what you're looking for:

[Divvy](https://mizage.com/windivvy/):

> With Divvy, it’s as simple as a single click and drag in the Divvy interface and your window will be resized and moved to a relative portion of the screen. If that seems like too much work, you can go ahead and create as many different shortcuts as you’d like that resize and move your windows.

[GridMove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html):

> GridMove is a program that aims at making windows management easier. It helps you with this task by defining a visual grid on your desktop, to which you can easily snap windows. This program comes bundled with some predefined grid templates, that can be easily swaped, but also has ways of creating custom grids or sharing grids made by others.

[Winsplit-Revolution](http://winsplit-revolution.com/):

> WinSplit Revolution is a small utility which allows you to easily organize your open windows by tiling, resizing and positioning them to make the best use of your desktop real estate.

[Maxto](http://maxto.net/):

> Define your own regions. You decide how your windows should be arranged. Whenever a window is maximized, it is maximized into the region where the mouse pointer is. You can also use keyboard shortcuts to quickly move windows to the correct region.

[Project Windy](https://projectwindy.codeplex.com/):

> It started as a windows alternative to divvy, but now it has evolved with into its own.

I've personally used Divvy on a Mac and had a good experience with it. When you activate it, it shows a grid that you can click and drag your cursor over to move the current window to. You can specify how many divisions there are in the grid width or height independently from 1 to 10. You can set up keyboard shortcuts for specific locations on the screen as well.